# How to append Object to Interface Array processing

Tags: arrays, object, interface, append, processing

```java
interface Creature {
   void display();
   void damage(int x);
}
class Beaver implements Creature {
    ....
}
class World {
    Creature[] creatures = new Creature[0];
    ...
    void spawnCreature(Creature c) {
        creatures = append(c, creatures);
    }
}
```

But i get an error:

cannot convert from Object to Skyland.Creature[]

Plz help

Comment: Please share the code of append function and also the line at which you are getting this error

Comment: the line was the one with the append() and append() is built in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions like these are best answered by looking at [the Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/append_.html).

The `append()` function takes two parameters: an array and a value, **in that order**. You're giving it a value and an array.

In other words, this line:

```
creatures = append(c, creatures);
```

Should be this:

```
creatures = append(creatures, c);
```

If you're still having trouble, please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a new question post. Good luck.